# How to enable buttons in Web View Dialogflow Integration

Tags: webview, bots, dialogflow-es

In intent I tried to add Google Assistant "Suggestion chip", I found
this in one of the tutorials, but it seems that it's not working anymore.
How I can add buttons into WebView Dialogflow chat?

Is this feature even existing in WebView Dialogflow?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer:
 Web View currently is in Demo mode. Meaning that it **does not supports** Buttons or "Suggestion chip".